# iOS >> Separated .h&.m Files to Manage a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

In my app there's a UITableView that appears in several different UIViewControllers - same data base, same design, same IB. The difference is that in each different UIViewController the UITableView size and specific data taken from the data base is different.

I thought of creating one set of .h&.m files that will manage these UITableViews for all the different UIViewControllers and then I can avoid duplicating the UITableView methods.

I'm familiar with how to do that for UIView by creating a new Objective-C Class file of type UIView. Is there a way to do the same for UITableView or do I need to create a UIView.m&.h files and have them be delegated to UITableView?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I misunderstood your question the first time - let me try again.

You want a class that can handle the datasource and delegate operations whereever the table is used. So this is a helper class, and it will be a subclass of NSObject. There are several ways to configure this - that said, you will almost for sure need a "delegate" - the object that instantiates this class and with whom you will most likely need to update as things happen.

- So create a protocol - as you design this you will find out exactly what needs there as you code the class and try to use it.
- to populate this class you have several methods:

1) use an NSArray property, and populate the array with dictionaries. Each dictionary will have the info for one row. Or if multiple sections, the array has arrays, each of the latter containing dictionaries with the information to populate cells with.

2) provide a large number of properties on the class that contain the information to configure each cell with

3) use the protocol to request information from the "owner" class on an as needed basis.

Comment: Thanks David. Even though I understand how class methods work, I have to say that I have never yet created a my own class with class methods. So I want to make sure i understand how to implement it. So... what i should do is have any class type (NSObject, UIView, etc...) and implement all the UITableView relevant methods; and then implement these 2 Class Methods (+ and not -) and then in the UIViewControllers have something like "UITableView*myTV = [MyClass specialTableWithFrame:etc...]"? Please tell me if I'm in the right direction